# Error when configuring TLS/SSL for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ssl, mongo-shell

I have an existing MongoDB Instance on my server. I wanted to enable SSH for it. I edited the /etc/mongod.conf as follows and added the TLS Options

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /path/to/privatekey.pem


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
security:
    authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Whenever I try to restart MongoDB by running `sudo service mongod restart` I face the following error:

> ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-12-24 04:32:58 IST; 2s ago
> Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
> Process: 72902 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Main PID: 72902 (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Dec 24 04:32:58 tcp-server-1 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database
> Server. Dec 24 04:32:58 tcp-server-1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main
> process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Dec 24 04:32:58
> tcp-server-1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'.

But if I comment out the TLS Options, then its working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `/path/to/privatekey.pem` also contain the signed certificate?

Comment: @Joe yes, it contains the certificate as well